# Resultado do banco de dados no inputText

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, front-end

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em *JSP* e gostaria de pegar o código máximo dos produtos cadastrados no banco de dados e colocar no campo de texto.

```html
<input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo"/>
```

Mas não estou conseguindo.

Eis o meu JSP:

```html
  <%

    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    try {
        con = Conecta.conexao();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Produtos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    Produtos pro = new Produtos();

    try {

        String sql = "SELECT max(prod_cod) AS prod_cod FROM tb_produtos";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            pro.setProd_codigo(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("prod_cod")) + 1);

        } else {
            pro.setProd_codigo(1);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro" + e);
    }


%>

<form method="get" action="CadastroProdutos2" >

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4"><h2>Cadastro de Produtos</h2></div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="conteudo_cadastro"> 

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    Nome do produto:<input type="text" id="nome_produto2" name="nome_produto"><br/><br/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    Descrição:<input type="text" id="descricao" name="descricao"><br/><br/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    Valor:<input type="text" id="valor" name="valor"><br/><br/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    Cor:<input type="text" id="cor" name="cor"><br/><br/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    Marca:<input type="text" id="marca" name="marca"><br/><br/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    Tamanho:<input type="text" id="tamanho" name="tamanho"><br/><br/>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    Parcelas:<input type="text" id="parcelas" name="parcelas"><br/><br/>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    Tecido:<input type="text" id="tecido" name="tecido"><br/><br/>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    Codigo:<input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" value="${pro.getProd_codigo()}"/> <br/><br/>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/> <br/><br/>

                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button> 

</form>
```

Comment: Qual o problema ? Está sendo lançada alguma exceção ?

Comment: nenhuma exceção

Comment: O campo está simplesmente em branco, certo ?

Comment: sim, esta totalmente branco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou me basear na [minha resposta à sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/249296/132).

Há duas alternativas possíveis, calcular o valor do próximo código ao carregar a página ou usar *autoincrement*.

## Carregando o valor do próximo código

Na classe `ListagemProdutoServlet`, vamos alterar o método `doGet` para ficar assim:

```
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException
    {
        List<Produto> produtos = ProdutoDAO.instancia().listarTodos();
        request.setAttribute("produtos", produtos);

        int proximo = produtos.stream().mapToInt(Produto::getCodigo).max().orElse(0) + 1;
        request.setAttribute("proximo", proximo);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/produtos.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

No JSP, você usaria isso:

```html
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                Código: <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" value="<c:out ${proximo}" />
            </div>
```

Entretanto, essa não é uma boa abordagem. Se você abrir a tela de cadastro/listagem simultaneamente em duas abas no navegador, ambas obterão o mesmo código. Ao salvar a primeira delas, tudo ocorrerá bem, mas não vai funcionar ao tentar salvar a segunda.

A causa do problema é que você está colocando o código do produto na JSP para um produto que nem existe ainda. O correto seria definir o código quando o produto for criado. Portanto, recomendo a próxima abordagem, com base em *autoincrement*.

## Usando *autoincrement*

Primeiro, no banco de dados, você define o campo `prod_cod` da tabela `tb_produtos` como *autoincrement*.

Depois, você deleta da sua JSP o campo do código na parte de cadastro.

Em seguida, no seu DAO, o método `salvar` fica assim:

```
    private static final String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO tb_produtos (prod_nome, prod_desc, prod_valor, prod_marca, prod_tamanho, prod_parcelas, prod_tecido, prod_tipo_imagem, prod_imagem) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    public void salvar(Produto pro, ImagemProduto im) {
        try (
            Connection con = Conecta.conexao();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
        ) {
            ps.setString(1, pro.getNome());
            ps.setString(2, pro.getDescricao());
            ps.setDouble(3, pro.getValor());
            ps.setString(4, pro.getMarca());
            ps.setString(5, pro.getTamanho());
            ps.setInt(6, pro.getParcelas());
            ps.setString(7, pro.getTecido());
            ps.setString(8, im.getFormato());
            ps.setBytes(9, im.getConteudo());
            ps.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

E então, na classe `SalvarProdutoServlet`, você troca essa linha:

```
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
```

Por isso:

```
    int id = 0; // O id ainda é desconhecido e não foi gerado ainda.
```