# Imagem não aparece na table JSP

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Gravei no meu banco de dados uma imagem em que fiz o upload dela na minha página HTML. Ele salva a imagem em bytes no meu banco de dados, mas ao mostrar ela em uma tabela, ela não aparece.

UPDATE

Minha HTML no meu JSP:

```
<h3>Lista de Produtos Cadastrados</h3>

      <table border="1">
      <tr>
          <th>Codigo</th> 
          <th>Produto</th>
           <th>Nome</th>
           <th>Descricao</th>
           <th>Valor</th>
           <th>Marca</th>
           <th>Tamanho</th>
           <th>Parcelas</th>
          <th>Tecido</th>
      </tr>


      <c:forEach items="${requestScope.produtos}" var="registro">

          <tr>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.codigo}"/></td>
              <td> <img src="<c:url value="/produto/imagens=?id=${registro.codigo}"/>"</td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.nome}"/></td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.descricao}"/></td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.valor}"/></td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.marca}"/></td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.tamanho}"/></td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.parcelas}"/></td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.tecido}"/></td>
          </tr>


      </c:forEach>





  </table>
```

Ao cadastrar os produtos corretamente, é redirecionada para a servlet `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/produtos/listar"})` que a servlet redireciona para pagina de CadastroProdutos que contem a table que ira mostrar os dados.
São apresentados todos os dados menos a imagem cadastrada

Minha Pagina de Cadastro de Produtos que contem a table que ira mostrar os dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha Servlet responsavel pelo cadastro

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {



    int id = 0;
    String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
    String descricao = request.getParameter("descricao");
    double valor = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("valor"));
    String marca = request.getParameter("marca");
    String tamanho = request.getParameter("tamanho");
    int parcelas = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("parcelas"));
    String tecido = request.getParameter("tecido");

    Part imagePart = request.getPart("file");
    String tipo = getFileType(imagePart);
    byte[] conteudo = imagePart == null ? new byte[0] : getBytesFromInputStream(imagePart.getInputStream());

    Produtos p = new Produtos(id, nome, descricao, valor, marca, tamanho, parcelas, tecido);
    ImagemProdutos im = new ImagemProdutos(tipo, conteudo);


    ProdutosDAO.instancia().salvar(p, im);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/produtos/listar");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);



}
```

Minha servlet responsavel por listar os dados

```
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/produtos/listar"})
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

     try {
        List<Produtos> produtos = ProdutosDAO.instancia().listarTodos();
        request.setAttribute("produtos", produtos);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/CadastroProdutos.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ListarProdutos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

Mina Servlet responsável por mostrar a imagem

```
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/produto/imagens"})
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //a imagem deve ser eniada por url, em uma servlet separada propria

    try {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Model.ImagemProdutos ip = ProdutosDAO.instancia().lerImagem(id);
        response.setContentType("image/" + ip.getFormato());
        response.getOutputStream().write(ip.getConteudo());


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImagemProdutosServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não deixe o seu método `Conecta.conexao()` lançar esse `ClassNotFoundException` e nem o seu DAO conhecer isso. Dê uma olhada [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242765/132) para ver como fazer isso. Além disso, acabei de testar o servlet da imagem isoladamente e funcionou: https://pastebin.com/AgPA7MXs

Comment: porque quando eu debugo isoladamente a servlet da imagem ele da null no  int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

Comment: ela da null por que quando eu abro a pagina CadastroPrdutos.jsp ele não mostra nenhum dado na table assim ele não envia o <td> <img src="<c:url value="/produto/imagens=?id=${registro.codigo}"/>"</td>

Comment: Tem um `=` a mais na URL que está no JSP. O `=` que está imediatamente antes do `?` não deveria estar lá.

Comment: eu acho Victor Stafusa que o erro ocorre aqui   <c:forEach items="${requestScope.produtos}" var="registro"> porque quando abro a pagina de CadastroProdutos.jsp ele não me retorna nenhum dado na tabela

Comment: ele só aparece os dados na table mas sem a imagem,após eu inserir um dado

Comment: A JSP só vai listar os dados se você acessá-la por meio do servlet `/produtos/listar`. Se você acessá-la diretamente, ela não vai encontrar os produtos porque eles são colocados dentro do `request` pela servlet.

Comment: Tentei com isso: https://pastebin.com/K5HjF1vr - Criei dois arquivos na pasta `C:\Projetos`: `setas1.png` e `setas2.png`. Quando acesso `http://localhost:8080/Imagens/produto/imagens=?id=1`, ele abre o `setas1.png`. Quando acesso o `http://localhost:8080/Imagens/produto/imagens=?id=2`, ele abre o `setas2.png`.

Comment: entendi Victor Stafusa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Onde está o seu problema

O problema está aqui:

```html
<img src="<%=registro.getImagem()%>" width="100" height="100" />
```

Você não mostrou como é o método `getImagem()` da sua classe `Produtos`, mas ao olhar para isso, dá para crer que ele retorne um array de bytes:

```
pro.setImagem(rs.getBytes("prod_imagem"));
```

O problema é que no HTML, a tag `src` serve para dizer qual é URL de onde a imagem pode ser baixada, e não para dar a sequência de bytes que correspondem a imagem.

## Tipo da imagem

Há ainda o problema que você não especifica o tipo da imagem. Vamos supor que possa ser "png", "jpeg" ou "gif" (em minúsculas). Adicione os métodos `getFormatoImagem()` e `setFormatoImagem(String)` na classe `Produtos` (além de um campo `private String tipoImagem)` e uma coluna `prod_tipo_imagem` na tabela `tb_produtos` do banco de dados. Caso o tipo daa imagem seja sempe o mesmo (por exemplo, todas elas forem "png"), isso não é necessário.

Tendo então um campo para o tipo da imagem, há pelo menos duas abordagens possíveis. A primeira seria utilizar uma [**data-uri em base-64**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) e a outra é com um servlet de imagens.

## A abordagem com data-uri

Você colocaria dessa forma:

```
<img src="data:image/<%=registro.getFormatoImagem()%>;base64,<%=new String(java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder​().encode(registro.getProd_codigo()))%>" width="100" height="100" />
```

Se a imagem for de um tipo fixo, você pode substituir o `<%=registro.getFormatoImagem()%>` pelo tipo dela (ex: "png").

Entretanto, essa abordagem não é muito vantajosa para imagens grandes ou muito numerosas, pois deixa o carregamento da página bem pesado. Por isso, vamos ver a outra abordagem.

## Servlet de imagens

Imagens são carregadas por meio de URLs. Então a solução seria dar uma URL para a imagem:

```
<img src="<%=request.getLocalName()%>:<%=request.getLocalPort()%>/images?id=<%=registro.getProd_codigo()%>" width="100" height="100" />
```

E então você tem que colocar um servlet para disponibilizar a resposta em bytes. Algo parecido com isso (supondo que você esteja usando Servlets 3.0 ou superior):

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/produto/imagens"})
public class ImagemServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException
    {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        ProdutosDAO dao = new ProdutosDAO();
        Produtos p = dao.mostrarProduto(id);
        response.setContentType("image/" + p.getFormatoImagem());
        response.getOutputStream().write(p.getImagem());
    }
}
```

Se o formato da imagem for fixo, você usaria `response.setContentType("image/png");`, por exemplo.

## Revendo o código da classe `Produtos`

Observe que você carrega os produtos junto com as suas imagens. Porém, carregar os bytes da imagem é algo pesado em termos de IO, de processamento e de memória. Além disso, ao montar uma instância de `Produtos`, apenas em alguns poucos casos você vai estar interessado em carregar os bytes da imagem. Em especial, se você fizer uma lista de produtos e encher ela com as imagens, vai estourar a memória do servidor facilmente. Agora que temos uma abordagem que trás as imagens separadamente do resto do conteúdo dos produtos, podemos separá-las.

O Java tem [**convenções de código**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/132) que é muito recomendável de serem seguidas. Isso significa que nomes como `setProd_desc` estão fora do padrão, o padrão seria `setProdutoDescricao`. Aliás, se a classe se chama `Produtos`, então o `Produto` no nome do método é redundante, e `setDescricao` já seria o bastante. Uma outra observação é que o nome da classe deveria estar no singular e não no plural.

[**Classes imutáveis**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/132) são mais fáceis de se trabalhar do que classe mutáveis, e a sua classe `Produto` é uma boa candidata a uma dessas. Além disso, [é uma boa prática que o construtor retorne um objeto já devidamente fabricado ao invés de um esqueleto a ser consertado depois ao chamar-se um monte de setters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/246036/132).

Considerando-se isso, assim ficam as suas classes:

```java
public final class Produto {
    private final int codigo;
    private final String nome;
    private final String descricao;
    private final double valor;
    private final String marca;
    private final String tamanho;
    private final int parcelas;
    private final String tecido;

    public Produto(
            int codigo,
            String nome,
            String descricao,
            double valor,
            String marca,
            String tamanho,
            int parcelas,
            String tecido)
    {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
        this.parcelas = parcelas;
        this.tecido = tecido;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public String getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public String getTamanho() {
        return tamanho;
    }

    public int getParcelas() {
        return parcelas;
    }

    public String getTecido() {
        return tecido;
    }
}
```

```java
public final class ImagemProduto {
    private final String formato;
    private final byte[] conteudo;

    public ImagemProduto(String formato, byte[] conteudo) {
        this.formato = formato;
        this.conteudo = conteudo;
    }

    public String getFormato() {
        return formato;
    }

    public byte[] getConteudo() {
        return conteudo;
    }
}
```

## Revendo o código da classe `ProdutosDAO`

A sua classe `ProdutosDAO` também precisa de revisão.

Em primeiro lugar, usar o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) é altamente recomendável para ter certeza de que você está fechando os recursos abertos adequadamente, além de não ter que ficar quebrando a cabeça escrevendo código chato para fazer esse tipo de trabalho.

Em segundo lugar, use os tipos genéricos adequados.

Em terceiro lugar, não use `JOptionPane` no DAO. O `JOptionPane` vai mostrar uma telinha de erro no servidor, onde ninguém estará olhando, e não no lado do cliente. Além disso, isso é uma violação do [padrão MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/132).

Em quarto lugar, diferentes instâncias de `ProdutoDAO` não são distinguíveis e têm todas o mesmo comportamento. Assim sendo, nem tem sentido haver mais de uma instância, e por isso podemos usar o padrão singleton:

Assim sendo, vamos re-elaborar o seu DAO, considerando a classe `Conecta` que você referenciou [nessa outra pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249256/132):

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProdutoDAO {

    private static final String LISTAR_SQL = "SELECT prod_cod, prod_nome, prod_desc, prod_valor, prod_marca, prod_tamanho, prod_parcelas, prod_tecido FROM tb_produtos";

    private static final String POR_ID_SQL = "SELECT prod_cod, prod_nome, prod_desc, prod_valor, prod_marca, prod_tamanho, prod_parcelas, prod_tecido FROM tb_produtos WHERE cod_prod = ?";

    private static final String IMAGEM_SQL = "SELECT prod_tipo_imagem, prod_imagem FROM tb_produtos WHERE prod_cod = ?";

    private static final String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO tb_produtos (prod_cod, prod_nome, prod_desc, prod_valor, prod_marca, prod_tamanho, prod_parcelas, prod_tecido, prod_tipo_imagem, prod_imagem) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private static final ProdutoDAO singleton = new ProdutoDAO();

    private ProdutoDAO() {
    }

    public static ProdutoDAO instancia() {
         return singleton;
    }

    private Produto lerProduto(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        int codigo = rs.getInt("prod_cod");
        String nome = rs.getString("prod_nome");
        String descricao = rs.getString("prod_desc");
        double valor = rs.getDouble("prod_valor");
        String marca = rs.getString("prod_marca");
        String tamanho = rs.getString("prod_tamanho");
        int parcelas = rs.getInt("prod_parcelas");
        String tecido = rs.getString("prod_tecido");
        return new Produto(codigo, nome, descricao, valor, marca, tamanho, parcelas, tecido);
    }

    private ImagemProduto lerImagem(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        String tipo = rs.getString("prod_tipo_imagem");
        byte[] conteudo = rs.getBytes("prod_imagem");
        return new ImagemProduto(tipo, conteudo);
    }

    public List<Produto> listarTodos() {
        try (
            Connection con = Conecta.conexao();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(LISTAR_SQL);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ) {
            List<Produto> lista = new ArrayList<>(); 
            while (rs.next()) {
                lista.add(lerProduto(rs));
            }
            return lista;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Produto lerProduto(int idProduto) {
        try (
            Connection con = Conecta.conexao();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(POR_ID_SQL);
        ) {
            ps.setParameter(1, idProduto);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                return lerProduto(rs);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public ImagemProduto lerImagem(int idProduto) {
        try (
            Connection con = Conecta.conexao();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(IMAGEM_SQL);
        ) {
            ps.setParameter(1, idProduto);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                return lerImagemProduto(rs);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void salvar(Produto pro, ImagemProduto im) {
        try (
            Connection con = Conecta.conexao();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
        ) {
            ps.setInt(1, pro.getCodigo());
            ps.setString(2, pro.getNome());
            ps.setString(3, pro.getDescricao());
            ps.setDouble(4, pro.getValor());
            ps.setString(5, pro.getMarca());
            ps.setString(6, pro.getTamanho());
            ps.setInt(7, pro.getParcelas());
            ps.setString(8, pro.getTecido());
            ps.setString(9, im.getFormato());
            ps.setBytes(10, im.getConteudo());
            ps.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que como você não especificou o que há na classe `Conecta`, mas decerto há coisas a melhorar nela.

Por fim, vamos aplicar as mudanças na nossa classe `ImagemServlet`:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/produto/imagens"})
public class ImagemServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException
    {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        ImagemProduto ip = ProdutoDAO.instancia().lerImagem(id);
        response.setContentType("image/" + ip.getFormato());
        response.getOutputStream().write(ip.getConteudo());
    }
}
```

## Definindo as servlets

Scriptlets são considerados odiados, ultrapassados e obsoletos. Misturar código Java enxertado em pedaços de HTML é uma coisa horrorosa a se fazer, e esse é um dos vários motivos pelo qual scriptlets devem ser abandonados. Além disso, o uso de scriptlets tende a levar a uma violação do [padrão MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/132).

O primeiro passo para eliminar os scriptlets é separar o comportamento em servlets para não ficar misturado com o JSP:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/produto/listar"})
public class ListagemProdutoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        List<Produto> produtos = ProdutoDAO.instancia().listarTodos();
        request.setAttribute("produtos", produtos);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/produtos.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/produto/salvar"})
@MultipartConfig
public class SalvarProdutoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
        String descricao = request.getParameter("descricao");
        double valor = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("valor"));
        String marca = request.getParameter("marca");
        String tamanho = request.getParameter("tamanho");
        int parcelas = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("parcelas"));
        String tecido = request.getParameter("tecido");

        Part imagePart = request.getPart("imagem");
        String tipo = getFileType(imagePart);
        byte[] conteudo = imagePart == null ? new byte[0] : getBytesFromInputStream(imagePart.getInputStream());

        Produto p = new Produto(id, nome, descricao, valor, marca, tamanho, parcelas, tecido);
        ImagemProduto im = new ImagemProduto(tipo, conteudo);

        ProdutoDAO.instancia().salvar(p, im);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/produtos/listar");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    private String getFileType(Part part) {
        if (part == null) return "";
        String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        for (String content : partHeader.split(";")) {
            String trimmedContent = content.trim();
            if (trimmedContent.startsWith("filename")) {
                String nomeEntreAspas = trimmedContent.substring(trimmedContent.indexOf('=') + 1);
                String nomeDoArquivo = nomeEntreAspas.trim().replace("\"", "");
                String extensao = nomeDoArquivo.substring(nomeDoArquivo.indexOf('.') + 1);
                return extensao;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];

        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        return os.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

O servlet `ListagemProdutoServlet` usa o DAO para ler a lista de produtos (sem as imagens, vez que essas são lidas no `ImagemServlet`) e colocar a lista lida na requisição. Em seguida, ele redireciona para o JSP `produtos.jsp`.

Já o servet `SalvarProdutoServlet` usa o DAO para salvar o produto e redireciona para o `ListagemProdutoServlet` que irá ler a lista de produtos e redirecionar ao `produtos.jsp`. O `SalvarProdutoServlet` é um servlet multipart (veja mais sobre isso [**aqui**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html)).

O método `getBytesFromInputStream` é o responsável por ler um `InputStream` por completo (que corresponde ao arquivo submetido) e com isso fornecer um array de bytes que contém o conteúdo do arquivo. Peguei ele [desta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17861016/540552).

Se/quando você começar a usar o Java 9, a parte do `getBytesFromInputStream(imagePart.getInputStream())` poderia/poderá ser substituída por `imagePart.getInputStream().readAllBytes()`, e com isso o método `getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream)` tornar-se-ia desnecessário. Com o novo método [**`readAllBytes()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--) do Java 9, poderíamos pegar o conteúdo inteiro do arquivo enviado de uma forma mais simples.

Você ainda vai precisar alterar o `SalvarProdutoServlet` para verificar se todos os dados que deveriam ser passados estão presentes e se foram preenchidos de forma válida antes de realizar a inserção no DAO de fato.

## Revisando o código da sua JSP

Supondo que a sua JSP seja a página `produtos.jsp` a qual me referi, agora que já temos a lógica de acesso ao banco de dados dentro de servlets, só resta ao JSP a exibição dos dados.

Com o uso de JSTL e de [EL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html), podemos então enfim eliminar todos os scriptlets. Eis o código resultante:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Listagem de produtos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<c:url value="/produto/salvar" />" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-6 col-md-4"><h2>Cadastro de Produtos</h2></div>
                <div class="col-6 col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="conteudo_cadastro"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        Nome do produto: <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        Descrição: <input type="text" id="descricao" name="descricao" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        Valor: <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <!--div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        Cor: <input type="text" id="cor" name="cor" />
                    </div -->

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        Marca: <input type="text" id="marca" name="marca" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        Tamanho: <input type="text" id="tamanho" name="tamanho" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        Parcelas: <input type="text" id="parcelas" name="parcelas" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        Tecido: <input type="text" id="tecido" name="tecido" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        Código: <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        Arquivo: <input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <h3>Lista de Produtos Cadastrados</h3>

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th> 
                <th>Foto</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Marca</th>
                <th>Tamanho</th>
                <th>Parcelas</th>
                <th>Tecido</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach items="${requestScope.produtos}" var="registro">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${registro.codigo}" /></td>
                    <td><img src="<c:url value="/produto/imagens?id=${registro.codigo}" />"</td>
                    <td><c:out value="${registro.nome}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${registro.descricao}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${registro.valor}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${registro.marca}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${registro.tamanho}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${registro.parcelas}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${registro.tecido}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Victor Stafusa obrigado por responder,coloquei o código que você postou mas aconteceu um erro na minha servlet que faz o cadastro dos produtos um cannot find symbol symbol:method readAllBytes() location: class InputStream, coloquei um UPDATE na pergunta e coloquei a linha e a causa do erro

Comment: @User1999 Qual é a versão do seu Java?

Comment: Uso o NetBeans IDE 8.2

Comment: @User1999 NetBeans é a sua IDE. O Java é independente do NetBeans. O NetBeans pode trabalhar com qualquer versão do Java. Entretanto, vou supor que você está no Java 8. Esse método aí foi acrescentado no Java 9, por isso que você não consegue usá-lo.

Comment: e agora como faço para ler  byte[] conteudo?

Comment: @User1999 Resposta editada. Acrescentei um método `getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream)` para fazer isso.

Comment: Victor Stafusa ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar o produto no banco de dados ao debugar o código do cadastro dos produtos na minha Servlet e passar o breakpoint na linha String tipo = getFileType(imagePart); ele lança um erro, editei minha pergunta e coloquei o código e o stack trace completo do erro

Comment: ele lança o erro java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1927)
Controler.CadastroProdutos2.getFileType(CadastroProdutos2.java:124)
Controler.CadastroProdutos2.doPost(CadastroProdutos2.java:100)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) na linha 124 do getFileContent

Comment: @User1999 Qual é o nome do arquivo que você tentou fazer o upload?

Comment: @User1999 Editei a resposta e alterei a linha onde o erro ocorre. Agora funciona?

Comment: Victor salvou os dados corretamente, mas agora o problema é outro, Ao cadastrar os produtos corretamente, é redirecionada para a servlet @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/produtos/listar"}) que essa servlet redireciona para pagina de CadastroProdutos que contem a table que ira mostrar os dados. São apresentados todos os dados menos a imagem Atualizei a pergunta e coloquei o código e a imagem do erro